# Importing Android Samples From The Developer Training Website Into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, android-studio

this might seem like a dumb question, but how do I import and run the sample code provided on the android developer training website into android studio and run them?

For example, I am trying to import the fragments sample code from here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html

I've downloaded this file as shown below:

[image: Downloaded File]

and imported using the import project (eclipse, etc) from the android studio start screen as shown below:

[image]

However, it does not seem to import properly in Android studio as I cannot run the app. Can anybody point me out as to what I am doing wrong? Thank you! :-)

**EDIT**

Error when importing:

[image]

Comment: Check the sample is design to run with `gradle` and compatible with `android studio`

Comment: what error do you get when you run the app?

Comment: what error is it giving you?

Comment: @NichoDiaz added screenshot of error

Comment: @MD How do I check that? :S

Comment: @the_archer FYI : you can also import sample through file->new->import sample. no need to download and import like this.

Comment: @KrupalShah Can't find any android training samples from the list, in this case the framents sample.

Comment: @the_archer this error is coming because in your sample,  minSDK/targetSDK is 15 and it is not installed in your SDK manager. you can either change it in build.gradle to different or install it in sdk manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download target SDK 15, the code has its target SDK set to 15, or you can change it from the main gradle file like

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
```

where targetSdkVersion is the maximum SDK you want to support